# Using memcpy from a pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, memcpy

I have a `typedef struct`named "item" that contains 2 `char[254]` (Name of product and Name of company) and 9 `int` variables. (Price, Amount,etc..).

I created a pointer from that `typedef struct` and one array(1D) and one Two Dimensional array.

I have used `scanf` to store data to the pointer's respective variables (No problem so far).

Now, I want to "copy and store" the data of the pointer's variables into the array (1D) then "copy and store" the data of the 1D array to the 2D array.

For pointer to 1D array, this is what I did:

```
void pointer_conversion(item *a, item curr[10000], int total)
{
memcpy(&curr[total], a, sizeof(item*));
} 
// Tried doing: memcpy(&curr[total],a,sizeof(item*) * 100); 
// Why 100?= just to be safe.  But still not working.
```

Now, this function copys and stores the first `char[254]` of the pointer `a` into 1D array `curr` but the rest of the variables of the `typedef struct` is `NULL`.

Any advice?

### (Using VS2012 on Windows)

```
typedef struct nodebase{
    char productname[254];
    char companyname[254];
    int price;
    int stocks;
//....
    struct nodebase *next; //Use the struct as linked-list
}item;
```

Comment: @ZacWrangler Fixed! Typo

Comment: @BeginnerC now think about what `sizeof(item*)` is. It isn't what you want. Also, this most certainly is a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [memcpy a buffer and an array not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780091/memcpy-a-buffer-and-an-array-not-working)

Comment: @H2CO3 Is it just the same thing when I am using `typedef struct`? Just asking

Comment: @beginnerC: yes, is the exact same thing: a failure in providing `memcpy()` with the correct size.

Comment: @H2CO3 But I have put `sizeof(item*)`. Won't that do?

Comment: @BeginnerC No. You don't want to copy a pointer-sized data chunk, do you? You rather want to copy a struct-sized one.

Comment: To be more clear: `sizeof(item*)` == sizeof of a pointer, while `sizeof(item)` == sizeof of `struct item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what the code fragment does,

- function returns void/nothing

  ```
  void
  ```
- function name is pointer_conversion, takes three arguments
- argument a is a pointer to item, (item*)
- argument curr is an array of item, (item[10000])
- argument total is an int

  ```
  pointer_conversion(item *a, item curr[10000], int total)
  {
  ```
- memcpy takes three arguments, destination, source, and number of bytes to copy
- how big is sizeof(item*)? it is as big as a pointer.
- how many bytes do you want to copy? how big is sizeof(item)?

  ```
  memcpy(&curr[total], a, sizeof(item*));
  }
  ```
- but you probably don't want to copy the item* next element of the item

Comment: Thank you so much! I got misleaded. ^^